# movie index in PostgreSQL 13.0

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

[image: I need to relact the movie names from the drama genre]

```
SELECT (nome_filme) filmes, (duracao) tempo
from filmes
     INNER JOIN filme_genero 
      INNER JOIN generos
      where nome_genero like 'drama%';
```

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 17:       INNER JOIN generos;
                                 ^
 (Sequel::DatabaseError)
```

preciso relacionar os filmes de drama com duracao de menos de 95 minutos.
mas para isso preciso relacionar a tabela filmes com a tabela generos.

---

I need to list drama films that are less than 95 minutes long.
but for that I need to relate the movies table with the genres table.

Comment: No need for parentheses in your SELECT clause. Your INNER JOIN's are going to need an ON clause containing the condition upon which the two tables are being joined. Like `FROM filmes INNER JOIN filme_genero ON filmes.id_filme = filme_genero.id_filme INNER JOIN generos ON filme_genero.id_genero = generos.id`.

Comment: `inner join` needs a join condition specified with `ON`. Additionally: enclosing column names in parentheses in the SELECT list is totally useless

Comment: Your JOIN conditions are missing, the ON part